# Spark with Kubernetes connecting to pod id, not address

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, amazon-eks

We have a k8s deployment of several services including Apache Spark. All services seem to be operational. Our application connects to the Spark master to submit a job using the k8s DNS service for the cluster where the master is called `spark-api` so we use `master=spark://spark-api:7077` and we use `spark.submit.deployMode=cluster`. We submit the job through the API not by the spark-submit script.

This will run the "driver" and all "executors" on the cluster and this part seems to work but there is a callback to the launching code in our app from some Spark process. For some reason it is trying to connect to `harness-64d97d6d6-4r4d8`, which is the **pod ID**, not the k8s cluster IP or DNS.

How could this **pod ID** be getting into the system? Spark somehow seems to think it is the address of the service that called it. Needless to say any connection to the k8s pod ID fails and so does the job.

Any idea how Spark could think the **pod ID** is an IP address or DNS name?

BTW if we run a small sample job with `master=local` all is well, but the same job executed with the above config tries to connect to the spurious pod ID.

BTW2: the k8s DNS for the calling pod is `harness-api`

Comment: You might be able to trick the submission process by setting the hostname of your container to `spark-api` so when it tries to advertise itself, it will use that name, but to be honest your question is unclear about which Pod in your story is `harness-64etcetc`

Comment: The pod submitting the Job to Spark has the pod ID of `harness-64etcetc` so the connection is coming back from Spark to the pod that launched the job but using this spurious name as if it is an address or name.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider to use [Headless](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services) service for `harness-64etcetc` Pod in order to accomplish backward DNS discovery. Actually, it will create particular endpoint for the relevant service by matching appropriate selector inside your application Pod and as result A record expects to be added into Kubernetes DNS configuration.

Eventually, I've found related [#266](https://github.com/kubernetes/dns/issues/266) Github issue, which probably can bring some useful information for further investigation.

Comment: Do you have a working sample. I don't think this may help here. I was testing it and finally ended up running both master and worker(s) containers in single pod. Good enough for me for my test environment. Please suggest how you did it using headless service so that I can try the same.